# Give buttons a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m trying to write a calculator. I already gave the buttons a function and let them write in the console but I don´t know how to create a textfield to write in.
Here is my code for an example button:

```
button1 = Tk.Button(main,text = "1",
                        height = 4,
                        width = 4,
                        command= lambda : onclick(1))
    button1.place(x = 25, y = 25)
```

and then I gave it a function:

```
def onclick(args): 
    if args == 1:
        print("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of widgets to chose from: `Label`, `Entry`, `Text`, `ListBox`, .. You can check [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) for a list of available widgets. If you want to use a label, you could try the following:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def onclick(args):
    if args==1:
        print("1")
        label.config(text=f"You clicked: {args}")

root = Tk()

button1 = Button(root, text="1", height=4, width=4, command=lambda: onclick(1))
button1.place(x=25, y=25)
label = Label(root, text="Nothing clicked")
label.place(x=75, y=25)

root.mainloop()
```

Also, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time :) good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it again!